# jQuery UI nested sortable drop area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, nested-sortable

I'm trying to connect two lists using the nestedSortable plugin by msjarfatti (https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable)

I've set up a test here http://jsfiddle.net/gcWQQ/46/

HTML:

```
<h4>SELECTIONS</h4>
<ul id="selections">
    <li><div>Section 1.0</div></li>
</ul>
<br>
<h4>CONTENT SET</h4>
<ul id="content">
<li>
    <div><h4>Headline Here</h4><p>Metadata here</p><p>Article snippet goes here and it can get to be very long. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Blah blah more text here.</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div><h4>Headline Here</h4><p>Metadata here</p><p>Article snippet goes here and it can get to be very long. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Blah blah more text here.</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div><h4>Headline Here</h4><p>Metadata here</p><p>Article snippet goes here and it can get to be very long. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Blah blah more text here.</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div><h4>Headline Here</h4><p>Metadata here</p><p>Article snippet goes here and it can get to be very long. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Blah blah more text here.</p></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("ul, li").disableSelection();

$('#selections').nestedSortable({
listType: 'ul',
toleranceElement: 'div',
items: 'li',
tolerance:"pointer",
});

$('#content').nestedSortable({
listType : "ul",
handle:"div",
toleranceElement:"div",
helper:'clone',
items: 'li',
connectWith:'#selections',
});
```

I am able to drag from the CONTENT area to the top level of SELECTIONS but trying to drag into a nested position isn't really working. If you drag all the way to the right almost off the page it sometimes works.

Answer (score 0):

Put your HTML inside a *DIV* with a fixed width & you'll be on your way.

Also you could add a common class on the two *UL* in order to simplify your JS code. Assume you add the class «*.connected-lists*» on the two *UL*, all your JS could be replaced by something like this:

```
$('#selections, #content').nestedSortable({
    listType: 'ul',
    items: 'li',
    handle:'div',
    toleranceElement: '> div',
    tolerance:'intersec',
    helper:'clone',
    connectWith:'.connected-lists'
}).disableSelection();
```

**Note:** it could be a good thing to use the *placeholder* related settings to have a better idea of what is going on.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-placeholder

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-forcePlaceholderSize